# I can't see the detail by following each language in the loading

Tags: javascript, algorithm, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Anyone can you help me please? I want to present the detail by following each language(english,french,khmer) from parent class. I initialize the variable as English in the constructor.I try to display the existed document follow each language but it still doesn't see.here my code!

**Initialize the variable**

```
 this.events.subscribe('renderViewLang-' + this.documentId, (lang: any) => {
      this.currentViewlanguage = lang;
      setTimeout(() => {
       this.buildContentAsHTML();
      }, 1000);
    });
```

**display first loading**

```
    public ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad DetailTabContentPage[' + this.documentId + ']');
    this.alertService.showLoading();
    this.docSRV.getDocument(this.documentId, 1)
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.docContentDTO = data; 
        setTimeout(() => {
        if(this.currentViewlanguage === 'en'){
            if(this.docContentDTO !== null) {
              this.currentViewlanguage = 'en';
              this.buildContentAsHTML();
           } 
        } else if (this.currentViewlanguage === 'fr') {
            if(this.docContentDTO !== null) {
              this.currentViewlanguage = 'fr';
              this.buildContentAsHTML();
            }
        } else if (this.currentViewlanguage === 'kh') {
            if(this.docContentDTO !=  null) {
              this.currentViewlanguage = 'kh';
              this.buildContentAsHTML();
            }
        } 
        }, 1000);
      },
      error => {
        this.alertService.showError(error);
      },
      () => { // complete
        this.alertService.dismissLoading();
      });
  }
```

Comment: You only "change" the language when it must already have changed, so that will never happen. This: `if (this.currentViewlanguage === 'kh') .... this.currentViewlanguage = 'kh'` ... is obviously useless. Think how you can get in that `if` block? What is the language? Why still set it to the *same* language? Also, you never `publish` the event you subscribe to.

Comment: if i change this.docContentDTO !== null to this.docContentDTO === null all and different language in each condition..but it still doesn't work

Comment: do u have any idea to help me?

Comment: Don't just change `this.docContentDTO !== null`... you must review the logic. Put some debugging code to see which blocks are executed and which not.

Comment: yes i try to console.log() but when i click on it ...it never show that console